# How Do I Remove The Border Around My Images?

Tags: css

Hi I'm using wordpress and i am using the gallery shortcode, but the problem is that my images have borders around them.

I set the padding to 0 and i set the border to 0 in css but my thumbnails still have borders around them.

Here is the css ---> https://gist.github.com/mihadaiko/5011743#file-style-css

and here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to use css

```
img { border: none; }
```

Comment: Probably should target the element more then to say that all images should have no border.

Comment: this is correct. this will override the css rule for: #gallery-1 img

Comment: That won't work, and no images on the site have border, but for some reason those thumbnails have borders, have u seen my css

Comment: Does it have that border in all browsers?

Comment: I'm guessing there is another stylesheet involved somewhere. If you have google chrome, or firebug, right click on the image and inspect element. This will tell you what css styles are being applied to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a img { border: 0 none; }
```

Also added your code in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HkTDK/2/ and there are no borders on images, so it might be inherited from somewhere else.

Another solution would be to add:

```
#gallery-1 a, #gallery-1 img { border:0 none !important; }
```

If this doesn't work, it means that border is a background image, so just add background: none !important too to the above line

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot!
works perfectly for Wordpress if you are using Elementor.
If you are using several galleries (1,2,...,n) u need to add to your Custom CSS:

```
#gallery-1 a, #gallery-1 img { border:0 none !important; }
#gallery-2 a, #gallery-2 img { border:0 none !important; }
...
#gallery-n a, #gallery-n img { border:0 none !important; }
```

and so on.